# how to replace an action in a menu?

Tags: c++, qt, menu

For example, I have a menu and add an action in it somewhere. And after some time I want to replace the action by a new one because it becomes invalid. How to implement it?

```
QMenu* menu = new QMenu(this);
... 
QAction* action = menu->addAction("text");
...

QAction* newAction = new QAction(menu);

// how to replace?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// To replace action with yetAnotherAction:

 menu->insertAction(action,yetAnotherAction);
 menu->removeAction(action);
```